# Security implications of a simple autofill bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, security, bookmarklet

At work I often need to log in to different internal portals, for HR, travel booking and so on. Each portal has a different set of login details.

Browser extensions are blocked, meaning I cannot use a pw manager, so rather than reuse details or insecurely write them down, I wrote a very simple bookmarklet to autofill my details on each portal. It works via a single hardcoded js object that stores all my username and passwords against the domain name of each portal (about half a dozen in total). Running the bookmarklet checks the current site for a domain match and then autofills if a match is found.

Functionally it works brilliantly but I'm worried that I might be overlooking the security implications, especially as I am storing my passwords in plaintext in the bookmarklet, which is then injected into the page. My specific questions:

1. Assuming I don't have any bookmark cloud syncing turned on, do I need to be worried about physical access to the bookmarklet? No-one else uses my laptop but perhaps someone could log in on their own Windows account and access my user data?
2. Each time I run the bookmarklet it injects the whole script onto the page, which contains the js object storing **all** the passwords. Can the webpage owner somehow capture this and send it back to the server? Would this depend on whether my bookmarklet is globally or locally scoped?
3. Is there a better approach to this? I considered storing login details in a text file which the bookmarklet will open and read but this requires going through the File open dialog which is quite long-winded. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Sanitised bookmarklet code (annotations in square brackets):

```
javascript: (() => {
  Object.entries(
    {
      "[document.title]": {
        "[username input element ID]": "[username]",
        "[password input element ID]": "[password]",
      }, //[Other entries...]
    }[document.title]
  ).forEach(([k, v]) => (document.getElementById(k).value = v));
})();
```

Comment: _"Is there a better approach to this?"_ - use a proper password manager. _"Browser extensions are blocked"_ - then use one that provides a Web-UI as well.

Comment: Yep, I have most of my details in my Bitwarden Web Vault but I'm specifically looking for autofill functionality which this approach won't do.

Comment: (1) yes, (2) yes and (3) yes, do not roll your own crypto (or security relevant software)

Comment: The proper solution would be to open a ticket to your IT department and ask them for a solution.

Comment: 2. Webpage owner can already get your password if he/she wants to. I would restrict the bookmarklet to inject only the password to the website and not the other ones.

Comment: @JonasWilms Agreed that IT should provide a proper solution. Any chance you could elaborate on points 1 and 2. By what mechanism could a site owner capture the login details?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski That would be the ideal but I'm not sure how I would do that while keeping everything in a single bookmarklet. How would you implement that?

Comment: Give me your code and I might give you your passwords :)

Comment: @JonasWilms Added a sanitised version to the post

Comment: "*Do I need to be worried about physical access to the bookmarklet?*" - yes. Bookmarks are not stored with particular security measures, anyone who can access your files can access your passwords. "*Each time I run the bookmarklet it injects the whole script onto the page*" - not quite, it doesn't inject a `<script>` tag that can be read by the page or anything. It just runs the code. However, a webpage owner can trivially control `document.title` so that your bookmarklet will fill in any password in their form. "*I considered storing login details in a text file*" - nah, that's even worse

Comment: @Bergi That's a really helpful response, thank you. I hadn't thought about manipulating `document.title`. I originally used `document.domain` but I had two portals that used the same domain so there was a clash and so I changed it.

Regarding the text file, my logic was that at least the text file could be access controlled or password protected which might mitigate physical access via the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trivial example that mimics being another website, stealing your credentials for that site:

```html
<script>
document.title = "Google";
setTimeout(() => {
  const username = document.querySelector("#username").value;
  const password = document.querySelector("#password").value;
  console.log("Your stolen credentials are", { username, password });
}, 1000);
</script>
<div style="display:none">
<input id="username" />
<input id="password" />
</div>

<h1>Harmless Website</h1>

<script>
  // your addon gets injected
  Object.entries(
    {
      "Google": {
        "username": "super",
        "password": "secret",
      },
    }[document.title]
  ).forEach(([k, v]) => (document.getElementById(k).value = v));
</script>
```

I can think of multiple other ways to exploit the few lines of code you posted. The original code will likely contain even more attack vectors.

So, as this example shows, *do not roll your own security software*. If your company does not provide a way for you to store passwords securely, it's your companies fault and your IT department should urgently fix that.

Comment: "*I can think of multiple other ways to exploit the few lines of code you posted*" - I can't,  could you share some please?

Comment: A couple of thoughts on your example: 1. It just extracts the details I've autofilled. I'm not worried about this. The website is assumed to have access to this anyway. I'm worried about it capturing other details in my hardcoded js object. 2. A similar approach could be used for hand-typed information too, it doesn't point to any specific weakness in the bookmarklet. 3. It seems to assume my bookmarklet would run on page load. It wouldn't; it would run when clicked. Your example would only work if it ran in the time between entering the info and clicking submit - quite a short window!

Comment: Nonetheless, thanks for the response and I totally agree with the wisdom of not rolling my own security software in principle.

Comment: Lastly, I could add logic in the bookmarklet to click the submit button immediately after entering the details, which would prevent your exploit working entirely, right?

Comment: @Bergi getter in `document.title` to detect the script run? Overriding `Object.entries`? `Function.prototype.toString`? Just some ideas, they do not necessarily work cross realm. That sentence was rather meant as a general remark that fixing the document.title alone does not make the code secure

Comment: @JonasWilms Sure there's ways to detect when the script is running, but I don't see a way to access its code (`arguments.callee.caller.toString()` does not appear to work). Notice that the object passed to `Object.entries` is only the values for the current document, not the object with all the values, I don't think there's a way to intercept the property access on the object literal.

Comment: @Bergi true but this seems to be only a simplified version of the actual code, so maybe there are further vectors. Pure speculation though, and also slightly missing the point of the answer ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms Not a simplified version. All I did was remove the other entries and sanitise the details. I specifically wanted to keep the bookmarklet simple. Thank you both for the useful discussion. Discussing particular attack vectors was exactly what I was trying to get out of this so I appreciate your thoughts.